# Build zlib failed in MAC OS

Tags: macos, zlib

I download the zlib source code with below commands:

```
curl -f -L -- "http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/libpng/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz" > "zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz"
```

and configure it with `./configure --static`.
But when I type the make, it runs failed.
The whole log shows:

```
--------------log-----------------

/usr/bin/libtool -o libz.a adler32.o crc32.o deflate.o infback.o inffast.o inflate.o inftrees.o trees.o zutil.o compress.o uncompr.o gzclose.o gzlib.o gzread.o gzwrite.o 
libtool: unrecognized option `-o'

libtool: Try `libtool --help' for more information.

make: *** [libz.a] Error 1

--------------log-----------------
```

Why might be the cause of this failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me.  In fact I develop zlib on a Mac.  You must have another libtool installed.

Install or expose the correct libtool.

You can reinstall Xcode, and/or you might have to delete a libtool somewhere else (in /usr/local/bin, or who knows where) that might be masking the Xcode libtool.

From the comments, reinstalling Xcode resolved the problem.

`libtool -V` should say `Apple` something.  It should not fail.

Comment: It works in my other MAC. Yes, with the log output, I think the question is something wrong with the libtool. I tried reinstall the libtool, it still failed.

Comment: How did you "reinstall the libtool"?  From where?  What do you get when you put in `libtool --version`?  `libtool -V`?  The latter should work and say `Apple, Inc. version cctools-...`.  If the first one gives you a GNU libtool version, then that's the problem.

Comment: zhangting:zlib-1.2.8 tingzhang$ libtool --version
ltmain.sh (GNU libtool) 2.2.6b
Written by Gordon Matzigkeit <gord@gnu.ai.mit.edu>, 1996
Maybe I have the wrong libtool. ooh....

Comment: Thanks for your help. I reinstall the Xcode Command Line Tools, and the libtool -V show right output with "App"

Comment: Thanks for you help, I reinstall the Xcode Command Line Tools, and the libtool -V show "Apple Inc. version cctools-839".  Ahh.. all works fine. Thanks again.